# Paypal - create a custom Buy Now button

Tags: php, paypal

i want to create a custom but now (or another pay now paymnet... ) so i read the documetation at paypal.com ([Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH00W2J)). and i read about HTML variables.
so far i understand that for create a buy now with dynamic price i need to set the amount variable to my price.
seconds i have the item_name and item_id variables for information about the productd.

but my que's are, where do i set the acount that my client pay for? 
i mean where i set to where the money will transfer?

seconds, is there anyway to add an another data that will send back to my server after the payment complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a hosted button (saved at PayPal) then it knows which account to send the money to based on that.

If you're working with an non-hosted button then you would use the "business" parameter to pass the email address or merchant account ID of the account you want the money to go to.

You can use the "custom" parameter to pass your own custom data.  It's actually called "custom" and you can pass up to 256 characters into it.  It will then come back in PDT or IPN if you're using those, and it would also show up in the GetTransactionDetails API response.